# Ponteiros com argc e argv

Tags: c, ponteiro

Tenho o seguinte código pra executar no terminal. Ele verifica se o primeiro argumento é um '+' e depois faz a soma dos números seguintes.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, soma;
char oper;

oper = *argv[1];

soma = 0;


if(oper == '+'){
    for(i = 2; i <= argc; i++){
        soma = soma + atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    printf("Soma: %d", soma);
}
```

A dúvida é por que 
     `oper = *argv[1]`
necessita do ponteiro enquanto
    `atoi(argv[i])`
não precisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char * argv[]` se trata de um vetor de ponteiros do tipo `char *`.

Logo, ao acessar um dos elementos desse vetor por meio de `argv[i]`, você terá um ponteiro `char *`.

A função `atoi()` recebe como argumento um ponteiro do tipo `char *`, o que torna `atoi(argv[i])` perfeitamente válido.

Seria o mesmo que:

```
char * p = argv[i];
int n = atoi(p);
```

Quando você faz algo como:

```
char oper = *argv[1];
```

Você está lendo o primeiro caractere do segundo argumento da linha de comando. O que seria equivalente a:

```
char oper = argv[1][0];
```

Seu código poderia ser algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    int soma = 0;

    char oper = argv[1][0];

    if( oper == '+' )
    {
        for( i = 2; i < argc; i++ )
            soma += atoi( argv[i] );
    }

    printf( "Soma: %d\n", soma );

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
./xpto + 1 2 3 4 5
```

Saída:

```
Soma: 15
```

Comment: Mas então a função atoi que torna desnecessário o uso de ponteiro em argv[i]?